# Changing the text on a label in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, label, form-for

I have this code in my view (for the "debate" class):

```
<%= form_for(@debate) do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.label :proposition, :body %>
...
<% end %>
```

and this in my en.yml:

```
helpers:
  label:
    debate:
      body: "Testing label body"
```

that I copied from this page: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label

expecting that it would result in `<label for="debate_body">Testing label body</label>` being output to the page, but instead I get  `<label for="debate_proposition">body</label>`

I tried some other, things, like swapping "debate" with "proposition" in en.yml with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The example in the API does not use `form_for`, so you need to pass in the object to `label`. Since you *do* use `form_for`, that argument can be skipped. So the correct way would be:

```
<%= form_for(@debate) do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.label :proposition %>
...
<% end %>
```

And:

```
helpers:
  label:
    debate:
      proposition: "Testing label body"
```